# Visual Studio: (how) can I check in specific lines from a changeset, instead of simply the entire file?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

When using Git and the `Git GUI`, I'm used to highlighting one or more lines, right-click and use the selection as what I want to check-in. This way, I can for example create two check-ins from the same file: say fixed typos (not interesting) and new functionality (interesting for someone that checks the version history).

In Visual Studio, I can only check in the entire file, but not specific lines. In order to do this, I could:

1. copy the server-version and my local version to Notepad++ as two files,
2. compare the two files,
3. copy the selected changes to my reverted local version that I want
   to check in,
4. then check in the current changes,
5. and finally copy all the remaining changes to my local version so that all
   changes are back in my local version. (rinse and repeat for all separate changesets)

This is... not ideal.

Is there a way (perhaps via a client-side plugin) that I can select a part of a file to check-in, but leave the remainder un-checked in?

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to do a version control in other words. There are lott of them like git,SVN they are designed to do what you want.

Comment: Yes, I want to do version control. However I can already do this with Team Exporer > Pending Changes, which we've already set up. So instead of checkin in entire files, I want to be able to check in selected parts of the edit - *inside* Visual Studio (without an external program).

Comment: step 1: select some code.
Step 2: control + h
Step3: control + L
Done replace will work in the selected area only.